# CSS class precedence and why I did I have to use the !important override?

Tags: html, css

This is just a basic sample:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .rowDate {
     background-color: #28456c;
     color: #fff;
    }
    .floatRight {
     color: gray;
     padding-top: 1mm;
     padding-bottom: 1mm;
     padding-right: 2mm;
     float: right;
     text-align: right;
     font-size: 8pt;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-transform: none;
    }
    .textWhite {
     color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <table>
     <tr class="rowDate">
      <td>
      <div class="floatRight textWhite">
       This is some text</div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Result in Microsoft Expression Web:

[image: Sample]

In this sample it is doing what I want but the basic principles are there. I expected the text colour from `textWhite` to take precedence. This is stated [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/priority-of-a-class-when-there-are-two-classes-in-the-same-element) where it says:

> the **last one takes precedence**. Check out the links below it looks like you can use an `! important` rule to override the normal behaviour.

Yet, when I was using my fuller HTML / CSS code (which is displayed in a `CHtmlView` it was ignoring the `.textWhite` styling. When I viewed it in a browser it was like this:

[image: Inspect 1]

The only way I got it to work was by using `!important`:

[image: Inspect 2]

Why did I have to do this? I can't show the complete HTMl / CSS as it is quite lengthy and has real names in it. But if I must prepare a full sample I will.

## Update

So this is the snippet from my live CSS file:

```
.textWhite {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 3mm;
}
.cellBibleReading {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right-style: none;
}
.cellNotes {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;
}
.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}
.cellTheme {
    border-right-style: none;
}
.cellPosition {
    color: gray;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I can see that I have defined `.textWhite` before `.floatRight`. So you are saying in the comments that it is the order I define the classes that is imprtant rather than the order I declare them in the `class` attribute?

Comment: you can clearly see that the floatRight is after (line 100) than textwhite (line 59). Don't relay on order, increase the specificity instead

Comment: order inside class doesn't matter

Comment: With `!important` order will be ignored. On the other hand two `!important` property order will be followed.

Comment: Only order inside stylesheet matters.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity for more infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the order of css definitions for `floatRight` and `textWhite` ( write css style for `textWhite` at **after** of `floatRight`), you don't need to describe `!important` on `textWhite` style.

`floatRight` and `textWhite` are common styles, so it will be good to remove color style on `floatRight` selector.

```
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.textWhite {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove `color: gray;` out of `floatRight` because it will break my whole design up and I would have to create a new `.textGray` class and update all my XSL transformation script.

Comment: I have changed the order of the class definitions and removed the `!important` override. All good!